# How do I make integers optional in DRF

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer with an integer field

```
foo = serializers.IntegerField()
```

and I'd like that field to be optional. It seems obvious to me that

```
foo = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

should work, but it doesn't, I get the error message:

```
{"error":{"foo":["A valid integer is required."]
```

I though I said that it wasn't required. I also tried adding a default,

```
serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=42)
```

Am I missing something? Is this even possible?

Comment: can you post your model and view code?pls

Answer (score -1):

While using 'required = False'

> Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during
> deserialization.
> Setting this to False also allows the object attribute or dictionary key
> to be omitted from output when serializing the instance.

you should try setting: 'null=True'

> Normally an error will be raised if None is passed to a serializer field. Set this keyword argument to True if None should be considered a valid value.
>
> Defaults to False

for further reading [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)

Comment: I'm not passing None. I'm explicitly not passing that argument.